# How to prevent fake users creating account on our drupal 6 website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, spam

Lately I've started seeing a lot of users on my website and the usernames/emails seem like spam. I do have captcha as well. What is going on?

```
kathleenfentonzry   tiotelisco1977+fenton8995@outlook.com<br>

kristofertroywtq    selfraledig1988+troy7366@outlook.com<br>

mindyrichifnngaeeqe bosspesepe1985+rich1855@outlook.com<br>
```

Please let me know if I can somehow prevent this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function custom_url_rewrite_outbound(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
    if (preg_match('|^admin(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $path = 'user'. $matches[1];
    }
}

function custom_url_rewrite_inbound(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
    if (preg_match('|^backend(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $result = 'member'. $matches[1];
    }
    if (preg_match('|^admin(?![^/])(.*)|', $path, $matches)) {
        $result = '404'. $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Include the above code in your settings.php file. This will replace the paths on your site that contain "user" with "member". This prevented the spam for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use a module called Spambot (https://drupal.org/project/spambot) to prevent spam user registrations on my D6 site. It checks all new user registrations against the spam database at http://www.stopforumspam.com based on IP, Username, and Email. This has stopped 99.9% of the spam registrations I used to get.

Answer (score 0):

We have sites that have the same issue where the captcha is getting beaten. I use [Access rules](https://drupal.org/getting-started/6/admin/user/rules) to block certain email addresses that I assume are spam accounts. If that doesn't help the next thing we are using is [Mollom](http://mollom.com/) to block to spam content. Mollom won't help with spam accounts but it will stop the site from being flooded with spam.

Answer (score -3):

Add re-captcha on registration page!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, that is because you do not understand it!

Comment: Please elaborate your answer, how adding re-captcha would help the case?

Comment: This is the answer! There is nothing to elaborate further! For any Drupal developer/admin, re-captcha is not a new term!

Comment: thanks for the comments. I do however already use captcha (not recaptcha specifically though) but these users seem to get through that and create accounts. Should I assume these are actual humans signing up with the intention to spam?

Comment: Yes, definitely! Even I got some spam users registered on my websites even though I use re-captcha!